# python cache library

Tags: python, caching, memcached

Before reinventing the wheel, I was wondering if there was a non-Django cache library that was similar to the one provided with Django. Basically, it would allow different backends (ideally, file and memcached to start) to be used just like Django's cache, and then behave identically regardless of backend used.

I've seen some libraries that are designed just for memcached but I haven't seen one that is explicitly set up to handle multiple caching systems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at Beaker's documentation at https://beaker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/caching.html

Comment: It looks like it does what I want but I'm really not crazy about the implementation... thanks though!

Comment: Just had a look at its source code and I think it'll work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Beaker as said is the way to go. It supports multiple backends including Memcached.

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a shot then. Maybe it's just the documentation that I'm having trouble with. I'll take a look at some sample code.

Comment: I just looked at the source code, which is actually easier to understand than the documentation. I'm only interested in putting objects into the cache or retrieving them, so it looks like I'll just be using `cache.get` and `cache.put`?